# Set the "value" in Select ModelChoiceField from ORM data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using a ModelChoiceField and populating it directly from the ORM, but would like to specifically set the "VALUE" attribute.

I create my form object as such:

```
dog_breed = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Breeds.objects.all(),
    label='',
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={
        'id': 'dog-breeds',
        'class': 'select-standard'
    }))
```

**NOW:** Returns the following when rendered:

```
<option value="1">Black Lab</option> 
<option value="2">Golden Retriever</option>
```

**GOAL:** How can I set the "value" attribute so it renders as such:

```
<option value="Black Lab">Black Lab</option> 
<option value="Golden Retriever">Golden Retriever</option>
```

Comment: If you do that when you save your form they will try to save yiyr ud as this text values

Comment: Nothing is being saved on form submit, I'm only passing the selected value to the ORM

Comment: But why not pass the id?

Comment: I need the friendly text to display on the next form. Is there a way to pass that to the POST instead of the "value"?

Answer (score 0):

override your form to this:

```
dog_breed = forms.ModelChoiceField(
   queryset=Breeds.objects.all(),
   to_field_name='name' # or what you want field name that exists in Breeds model
   label='',
   widget=forms.Select(attrs={
       'id': 'dog-breeds',
       'class': 'select-standard'
   }))
```

Comment: hey Soyuzbek Orozbek Uulu, thanks, that worked exactly like what I was wanting. One small correction, it was actually `to_field_name` but once I realized the typo it started working. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I don't see your 'up' on my answer?

Comment: If my answer useful for you , then you can like it up button on my answer.